# SPI pins logic level issue

Tags: embedded, logic-level, dot-matrix-display

I have ESP32 and the popular dot matrix module MAX7219 8*8 module to interface. It is connected through SPI pins. After a sample word printing on the maxtix it shows garbage outputs. Is it happening due to the logic level issue? Because the dot matrix works on 5V and ESP32 has 3.3v.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to do much more debugging on your own. What's the acceptable input logic levels, according to the data sheet? What does the ESP32 output?

Comment: It is indeed out of spec, but I wouldn't be surprised if once the levels are boosted there turns out to be another problem more directly causative problem like a software or wiring mistake as well.

Answer (score 2):

Page 3 of [the MAX7129 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf) specifies a minimum logic-high input voltage \$\mathrm{V_{IH}}\$ of 3.5V. So if your ESP32 is a 3.3V device then it cannot provide a high enough voltage to reliably operate the MAX7129. So yes, voltage levels / logic levels are probably the culprit here.